# Does SObjectType Access Guarantee Id Access?

Tags: permissions, salesforce-id, fls, dynamic-apex, describes

I am writing a fluent query builder which I hope will pass security review, and I still have a few nagging questions. I will refrain from asking more than one question per question, so right now, what I would like to know is:

**If a user can access a given `SObjectType`, is it guaranteed they can access its `Id` field?**

In other words, if we know:

```
someSObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()
```

is it then guaranteed that:

```
someSObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('Id').getDescribe().isAccessible()
```

It seems like it *should* be the case, but I'm not 100% certain and haven't yet been able to find any concrete confirmation in writing. The reason I want to know is that one of the steps filters out every field which is not accessible from the `SELECT` clause, and then if there are none left, I add back in `Id`.

Comment: I would think so as you cannot set fls for the id but can't provide docs. Just my 2 cents

Comment: @Eric Yeah that's where I'm at as well. It seems like a reasonable inference but I would like *certainty*.

Comment: I don't remember where I read it, but non-aggregate SOQL queries implicitly include the `ID` field (and after some testing, it looks like the `RecordTypeID` field as well) even if it isn't on the field list.  This isn't a definite answer but it seems to suggest anyone with access to an object is intended to be able to view it's `ID` and `RecordTypeID`.

Comment: As a comment, I'd say that I *have* answered questions about objects with non-unique/missing Id fields, but it'd take me a decent amount of data mining to find the answer of the thousands I've written.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian That's a good point. I think that's specific to SOQL in Apex but still another interesting data point.

Comment: @AdrianLarson The ID is also implicitly accessible if the person can access the record's detail page, since it's in the URL.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian These points of evidence have occurred to me and would be at least the beginnings of a good answer in their own right. I guess I should have included them in my question.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian That (query implicitly grabbing the Id field) sounds like something I wrote in an answer in the recent-ish past. Can't seem to find it though. I also found that if the driving SObject of the query has more than one `recordtype` defined for it, `recordTypeId` is also implicitly queried. The big caveat to this is I've only tested this using my sysadmin privileges (so I'm not sure how it behaves when things like sharing rules and other permissions come into play).

Answer (score 3):

All records that you can view in the UI should have an Id, because that's how they're displayed and referenced in the database. There are actually a small handful of objects that either do not have an Id (you can query the field but all values will be null), do not have a unique Id (e.g. the Id field will contain duplicates), or do not have an Id field you can query.

Generally speaking, if you can find the object in the Salesforce documentation, it will have an Id field that is non-null and unique. I have a nagging memory I can't quite place that there may be one or two objects that are documented that don't have an Id, but I can't seem to find them at the moment; virtually every object you use on a daily basis has an Id. The Salesforce WSDL "guarantees" that sObject types have an Id, as the base sObject type in the WSDL has Id defined.

Other objects that we can discover through describe calls, key prefix scanning, etc, may or may not have an Id field, or have non-unique Id values. One such object is the ApexPageInfo object, which is undocumented, may be queried and described, and all records we query have the null Id 000000000000000AAA.

I have occasionally run across other objects that exhibit odd behavior, like refusing to be described, having literally no fields, or other oddities. However, as long as you're limiting yourself to objects that appear in Schema.getGlobalDescribe(), the records should have an Id field that is visible, queryable, not-null, and unique.

If you allow the user to type in any random string instead, a user might stumble across an object that is outside the documentation, and thus subject to unusual behavior.

Comment: You don't really touch on objects which *do* have an Id field. Is there something more definitive there?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Took me a bit, but I found an example of an "odd" object. It seems that anything in the documentation should have an Id, but if you start digging into hidden objects, you'll find some gems that will annoy you.